# Lua script config

Tags: lua, luarocks

Currently , I use **luaver** to install the 5.3.5 version of lua

But when I use **luarocks** to install library, it always download latest lua 5.4.3 version.

And the package cannot be installed in my 5.3.5 version of lua.

I tried both

```
luarocks --lua-version 5.3.5 install luasocket
```

but it throws

```
No results matching query were found for Lua 5.3.5.
```

and

```
luarocks --lua-dir="my lua path in luaver" install luasocket
```

It throws

```
Lua interpreter not found at
```

Comment: did you try setting your default `lua_version` to `5.3.5`? `luarocks config lua_version 5.3.5`

Comment: There is already a solution right here on StackOverFlow. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42605658/error-no-results-matching-query-were-found-for-luarocks-in-ubuntu

Comment: thank you, all.

I give up with lua 